# Is there advantage of using in CSS #image-box vs #image_box (hyphen vs underscore)?

Tags: css, naming-conventions

Or is it just mainly a personal preference?

As a programmer I always use underscore, but have seen it as `-` and so I will have to conform to it working in that project.

Comment: Are you seriously concerned about this?  If so... **WHY?!**

Comment: because i see a big project using #image-box (using hyphens) throughout the entire project, and kind of wonder why.

Comment: Lot of dupes here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+underscore+hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand hyphens to be more SEO friendly for URLs. This *may* cary over in some odd case to CSS class and id names, although I can't think of any particular instance off the top of my head.

Both are valid, I think it just breaks down to personal preference.

Comment: Aside: this is (allegedly) because search engines treat "pickle_sandwich" as one keyword, but would split "pickle-sandwich" into two. The hyphen thus allows searching for either order of the words "sandwich pickle" or "pickle sandwich" whereas the underscore restricts the word order.

Comment: you mean some search engines may use element's ID and class to classify the content?  that could be huh, if they see main-div vs main_div or mainDiv.

Comment: That's what I mean, *maybe*, **some** search engines would also consider this. I don't know of any concrete evidence, just speculation. bottom line is personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

To-may-toe, To_mah_toe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came to some situation where using hyphen is better too -- when we grep for our code, if we grep for "image-box", then the programming code such as `add_to_image_box` won't cluster up the results.  As since it is more search engine friendly, I think it is a pretty good practice to use the form `image-box` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think hyphens are any better for SEO. That's why people try to avoid domain names with hyphen. We should not be confused for hyphen in search box or address bar of the browser. Hyphen in address bar is totally different world from programming.

I had few problems with hyphen not sure why but image names, database and table names and files and directories with hyphen give problem in some cases (specially in css). So, I do not recommend hyphen and always follow underscore.

check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10768014/1419238

If anyone know the reason for this, please share your knowledge